# MWS method to get list of offers (including seller IDs)

Tags: amazon-mws

Is there a method to retrieve the list of current offers (with price) for a specified ASIN if I do not have the product in inventory (I know it is possible to get this information through AnyOfferChangedNotification if I have an active listing for this ASIN)?

Do you know if there is a way to do this with MWS? I could not find one :frowning: Or do you know if there is another third-party API or another way to do this? I looked into Keepa but I need to get an update every time the lowest price changes and Keepa would be too expensive I think.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Does [GetCompetitivePricingForASIN](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/products/Products_GetCompetitivePricingForASIN.html) not work?  We use a number of these and I can't remember if we had to have the item in stock or not.

But a trick we used to use is to set the inventory = 1 for anything that was out of stock and then after a few minutes (after all the AnyOfferChangedNotifications fired), set the inventory level back to 0.  We used this method as a way to keep our system in sync with the marketplace, even when we were OOS on an item.

Comment: So you were able to change inventory to 1 for any ASIN (regardless of whether or not you had sold it before) and it would automatically trigger AnyOfferChanged notifications (assuming all other setups done)? That would be great for us. To answer your question, I did try GetCompetitivePricingForASIN but it only returns prices, not sellerIDs (or maybe I am not passing the right parameters?) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Exactly, the notifications come within seconds and then we quickly change the qty back to 0.   I think one of those operations returns seller IDs, but maybe my memory is failing.  I think the AnyOfferChanged notifications returns seller Id though.

Comment: Yep it does return the list of offers with seller IDs. For this use case, I need to track prices changes throughout the day. Doesn't the notification stop once you put it back to quantity=0?

Comment: fyi I am also discussing the issue there: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/mws-method-to-get-list-of-offers-including-seller-ids/458862/6

Comment: Yes they’ll stop but if you don’t have the product you can’t sell it. So it’s a temporary trick to see what competition is out there.